# Not able to render unicode character on Android device

Tags: android, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to use \u2029 for a paragraph break in a textview with a custom font applied but I'm getting a random x character instead. I know this custom font should support this character as I see it working on an iOS version.

Are some Android devices not able to render certain unicode characters even with a custom font? Why is this?

Comment: How is this a programmin question? And why would fonts affect the treatment of a control character?

Comment: @Rotwang My layout starts with that